# how to send just id to api with method post?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

The post method in my project is defined as follows:

```
  const post = (path, payload, callback) => {
      return service
        .request({
          method: "POST",
          url: path,
          responseType: "json",
          data: payload,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          if (response) callback(response.status, response.data);
        });
    };
```

And I just have to send the ID to the api.

```
 nameService(
           id,
          (status, data) => {
            if (status === 200)
              if (data.success) {
                props.notifySuccess(data.message);
                getTableData();
              } else props.notifyError(data.message);
            else props.notifyError(`خطای سرور: ${status}`);
          }
        );
```

What is being sent is like this:

> 22839:

But what I want is without two points:

> 22839

How to do this?

Comment: `data: payload.id` is this help you ?

Comment: no .Still the same==>22839:

Comment: from where are you passing this id, pls verify there once

Comment: Can you post code from where we can see how do you get value for payload variable?